# ESXi 6.0: halt command doesn't work in Centos VMs

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi

I have a ESXi 6.0 Hypervisor ( latest version as of today ) and i'm having some problems with Centos VMs.

"halt" command simply doesn't work. The VM will remain powered on but totally frozen ( console/network doesn't work ).

The only option to is to forcefully power off the VM.

Note: open-vm-tools is installed and working.

Is it possible to fix this somehow?

Comment: are you using 'halt -p'?

Comment: Why are you using halt? Shouldn't it just be `poweroff`?

Comment: @Chopper3 No, only using halt. I thought it would behave the same way it does for non virtualized installations.

Comment: It does - your issue is nothing to do with being virtualisation 'man halt' states you need -p